# How to display the word field for the game on kivy

Tags: python, kivy, game-development, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm making a python game using the kivy framework. I am faced with such a problem that it is impossible to make a field for a word. If you display only the game screen, then everything works. If you already have a full game with additional screens, then the selected letters appear, but the string does not. (Sorry for the inaccuracies in the question and for the incomprehensible code, I've been writing in python for less than six months)

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from random import *

Window.size = (400,600)



class Meneger(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class Menu(Screen):
    def click(self):
        click = SoundLoader.load('click.wav')
        click.play()


class Play(Screen):
    def click(self):
        click = SoundLoader.load('click.wav')
        click.play()

class Mod(Screen):
    def click(self):
        click = SoundLoader.load('click.wav')
        click.play()



class HangmanGame(Screen, Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    display_word = StringProperty()
    wrong_guess = 0
    correct_guess = 0

    def playsound(self):
        self.sound = SoundLoader.load('button.wav')
        self.sound.volume = 0.5
        self.sound.play()

    def FindHangmanWord(self):
        word_list = ['arrow', 'arson', 'artery', 'artful', 'artier', 'artist', 'arts', 'artsy', 'arty', 
                     'ascend', 'ascent', 'ascot', 'ashcan', 'ashed', 'ashen', 'ashes', 'ashier', 'ashing', 'ashore', 'ashram', 'ashy', 'aside', 'askew', 'asking', 'asks']
        word = choice(word_list)
        return word.upper()


    def check_in_word(self, btn):
        count = 0
        for i, letter in enumerate(wow):
            if btn.text == letter.upper():
                self.display_word = self.display_word[:i * 2] + btn.text + self.display_word[i * 2 + 1:]
                self.correct_guess += 1
                count += 1

                if self.correct_guess >= len(wow):
                    print('GAME OVER, YOU WIN')

            btn.disabled = True

        if count == 0:
            # count wrong guess
            self.wrong_guess += 1
            if self.wrong_guess >= 6:
                print('GAME OVER, YOU LOSE!')

    def init_display_word(self, word):
        tmp_display_word = ''
        for letter in word:
            tmp_display_word += '_ '
        self.display_word = tmp_display_word[:len(tmp_display_word) - 1]

class Info(Screen):
    def click(self):
        click = SoundLoader.load('click.wav')
        click.play()




presentation = Builder.load_file('my.kv')



class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        game = HangmanGame()
        game.init_display_word(wow)
        self.playsound()
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Menu(name='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(Play(name='play'))
        sm.add_widget(Info(name='info'))
        sm.add_widget(Mod(name='mod'))
        sm.add_widget(HangmanGame(name='hangmangame'))
        return sm


    def playsound(self):
        self.sound = SoundLoader.load('glav.wav')
        self.sound.volume = 0.5
        self.sound.play()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    wow = HangmanGame().FindHangmanWord()
    MyApp().run()
```

kv

```
    Label:
        id: display_word_id
        text: root.display_word
        font_size: 40
        color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
```

[the first screen is if I display one screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnsiO.png)
[the second screen is if I take out the whole game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTv7T.png)

I tried to write code in the second python file and import it into the main one, but to no avail. Also, instead of self, I inserted the class name (HangmanGame) into def init_display_word. It turned out to display the field throughout the game, but the selected letters were not displayed; and, on the contrary, there were letters in one screen, but the field disappeared. Even in def build, I inserted def check_in_word, but it requires a second argument, but it does not accept it itself.